# How to represent a large number in way so that it requires a smaller memory space

Tags: number-theory, binary

I have $25+$ digit numbers which I need to store in a manner that require least amount of memory space but at the same time represents the number exactly
For example: 
the number $34359738418$ can also be represented as $2^{35}+50$ which requires a smaller memory (has fewer bytes).
Would appreciate if someone can guide me towards a method to represent extremely large number

Comment: Are there (many) duplicates?

Comment: @MichaelStocker sorry did not get the question, If you are talking about digits yes there are quiet a few

Comment: No not, the digits. If there are duplicates among the numbers themselves you could use some kind of map. You could save a map of small numbers to your 25+ digit numbers and only reference the small numbers.
If there are no duplicates however, you only increase memory consumption.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your numbers have special known properties (which you don't tell us clearly) and belong to a specific subset of large numbers, this is impossible. Because with $b$ bits you can represent $2^b$ distinct numbers, not less, not more, and if $b<b'$, then $2^b<2^{b'}$. If you make some of the numbers shorter, others *must* become *longer*.

---

On another hand, if your numbers are not random but pseudo-random, and you know the generator, then with constant storage you will be able to recompute as many numbers as you want.

Comment: The numbers that are being generated are random and hence they dont fall in any particular subset. However, I am looking at any possible combination of mathematical functions not necessarily the one I have used in the example

Comment: @MayankBaid: your quest is hopeless.